# dimension of the vector space of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've been studying linear algebra. I know that the vector space of the functions over the reals is infinite. I think that the subspaces of the odd and even functions also have infinite dimensions. Is what I thought wrong? grateful for any help.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you  have a look already somewhere? What about the linear independent functions $x^n$ for $n$ even and odd?

Comment: yes, I already saw that the bases have infinite elements, both from the subspaces and from the space of the functions

Comment: @kots I think you're done then. If you find an infinite, linearly independent set in your vector space, then it must be infinite-dimensional (if it were of finite dimension $n$, linearly independent sets have maximum cardinality $n$). Since you have one of these sets for each of the odd and even functions, they must both be infinite-dimensional.

Comment: then, we can say that the dimension of the space of even functions has the same dimension as the space of odd functions, which in turn has the same dimension as the space of functions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know how much rigorous this is, but a clever way to think about why the subspace of even functions has infinite dimension is that it contains at least all functions of type $x^n$ with $n$ which is even (as @DietrichBurde pointed out in the comments), and, since they’re all linearly indipendent, its basis must “at least” be infinite because it must at least contain this infint number of linearly indipendent functions of type $x^n$ with even $n$. Thus, the space of even functions must have infinite dimensions.

In a similar way for the subspace of odd functions.

I think this way is at least helpful to remember yourself the reason behind this.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is very clear!

Comment: then, we can say that the dimension of the space of even functions has the same dimension as the space of odd functions, which in turn has the same dimension as the space of functions!

Comment: @kots I think that talking about “same dimensions“ for infinite dimensional spaces might be a little trickier, or at least not so intuitive, because talking about “same infinities” or “bigger infinities” might be involved: but I don’t know anything about this, so don’t take my words seriously.